# how to wake lock using powermanager class in android

Tags: android

hi i am trying to wake lock for a particular amount of time but i am not getting the result
i am using power manager class but i am not getting any result.
i am using this code to wake lock

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;

 PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");


        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 wl.acquire();

                 wl.release();
            }});
        }
```

here i am trying to invoke lock when i click button but its not working.
i need to lock when the particular time out using broad cast receiver please suggest me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly r u trying to do? I am not sure what are u xpecting from this code?

Answer (score 1):

you should:

1. hold a wakelock at first;
2. then do something. At the end;
3. release the wakelock.

so you should test it by:

```
    Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             wl.acquire();
        }});

    Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
             wl.release();
        }});
```

1. press button1
2. lock the screen for a test
3. press button2

what's more:

- PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK: Ensures that the CPU is running; the screen and keyboard
- FULL_WAKE_LOCK(I think it's you want):  Ensures that the screen and keyboard backlight are on at full brightness.

Answer (score 0):

You acquire and them immediatly release the WL. You have only to acquire WL in OnClick event and to handle a task to release it.
I suggest you to use also a mWakeLockAcquired boolean variable to check the WL state.